# Sort-Object -Unique

Tags: powershell, command-line

I'm making a script that collects all the subkeys from a specific location and converts the REG_BINARY keys to text, but for some reason I can't remove the duplicate results or sort them alphabetically.

PS: Unfortunately I need the solution to be executable from the command line.

**Code:**

```
$List = ForEach ($i In (Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:SOFTWARE\000' -Recurse)) {$i.Property | ForEach-Object {([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($i.GetValue($_)))} | Select-String -Pattern ':'}; ForEach ($i In [char[]]'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') {$List = $($List -Replace("$i`:", "`n$i`:")).Trim()}; $List | Sort-Object -Unique
```

**Test.reg**:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\000\Test1]
"HistorySZ1"="Test1"
"HistoryBIN1"=hex:43,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,00,44,00,2e,00,\
  7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,\
  00,43,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,\
  73,00,74,00,5c,00,42,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,\
  00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,00,41,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\000\Test2]
"HistorySZ2"="Test2"
"HistoryBIN2"=hex:4f,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,00,44,00,2e,00,\
  7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,\
  00,43,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,44,00,3a,00,5c,00,54,00,65,00,\
  73,00,74,00,5c,00,42,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00,41,00,3a,00,5c,\
  00,54,00,65,00,73,00,74,00,5c,00,41,00,2e,00,7a,00,69,00,70,00,5c,00,00,00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path strings that are encoded in your array of bytes are separated with `NUL` characters (code point `0x0`).

Therefore, you need to *split* your string by this character into an *array* of individual paths, on which you can then perform operations such as [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object):

You can represent a `NUL` character as `` "`0" `` in an expandable PowerShell string, or - inside a *regex* to pass to the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) - `\0`:

```
# Convert the byte array stored in the registry to a string.
$text = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($i.GetValue($_))

# Split the string into an *array* of strings by NUL.
# Note: -ne '' filters out empty elements (the one at the end, in your case).
$list = $text -split '\0' -ne ''

# Sort the list.
$list | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts I discovered that it is necessary to use the Split command to make the lines break and thus be able to organize the result.

```
{$List = ($List -Replace("$i`:", "`n$i`:")) -Split("`n")}
```